# Android audio recording set limit last x min

Tags: android, recording

we need recording should be done in a manner that records and overwrites the exiting recording so it will always provide the last X minutes as defined in the app settings.

```
int bufferSize = 2 * AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
            RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

recorder.startRecording();
int b = recorder.getState();
if (b == 1)
    recorder.startRecording();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i trying to save last x min recording.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include this information.